# Getting the exact amount of bits needed for a type in c++

Tags: c++

I have an array with bytes : `ByteSource byteSource` and I have a function

```
template<class target_t>
target_t BitReader<max_bytes>::readBits(size_t bitCount) {
```

In this function, I take bits out of the array (bitCount amount of bits) and put them into a T value.

After I am done with that, I have to check how many bits the target_t needs, if my bitcount is below that, I have to fill the value with 0's.

I am using `const size_t bits = sizeof(target_t) * 8;` but was wondering if this would be correct since in case I need for example 4 bits (instead a whole byte). Wouldn't I just be filling my value with 0's that aren't need?

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about your use case? I can see how you could get around wastage with a proxy object, but I'm not sure it's what you really need.

Comment: Note that you should probably use CHAR_BIT rather than 8 directly, it simply better documents what the intended use is.

Comment: * defined in `<climits>` as a macro https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Comment: Using `<numeric_limits>` it would be `sizeof(target_t)*std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits`.

Comment: @Peter Why not just `std::numeric_limits<target_t>::digits`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious   `std::numeric_limits` is not necessarily specialised for user-defined types (classes, structs, etc).   `digits` also has a different meaning for non-integral types.

Comment: @Peter I would image that if a user-defined type was used in that context you run the risk of getting an unexpected size due to potential padding and other possible implementation specific details (especially for polymorphic types).